# Pure CSS Accordion Issue: Holding Position

Tags: html, css, accordion

I'm trying to create a pure CSS Accordion, and pretty much have it working with radio buttons, the issue I am facing is that the accordion tends to shift the content off view.

Is there a way to keep the button/header at the top of the browser window?

Page can be found here http://jeyonline.com/lgc/#platform

(PS I know there is a lot of other issues with this page, just fixing the cosmetic ones right now).

Relevant CSS

```
/* Accordion */

.ac-container h3 {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-container h3:hover {
    background: #00AFFC;
}

.ac-container input:checked + h3,
.ac-container input:checked + h3:hover {
}

.ac-container h3:hover:after,
.ac-container input:checked + h3:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    right: 13px;
    top: 7px;
    background: transparent url(../images/arrow_down.png) no-repeat center center;  
}

.ac-container input:checked + h3:hover:after {
    background-image: url(../images/arrow_up.png);
}

.ac-container input {
    display: none;
}

.ac-container .ac-one, .ac-container .ac-two, .ac-container .ac-three, .ac-container .ac-four {
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.ac-container input:checked ~ .ac-one, .ac-container input:checked ~ .ac-two, .ac-container input:checked ~ .ac-three, .ac-container input:checked ~ .ac-four {
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.ac-container input:checked ~ .ac-one {
    height: 410px;
    background: url('../images/logo_who.jpg') no-repeat;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

    .ac-one h4, .ac-two h4, .ac-three h4, .ac-four h4 {
        padding-left: 60px;
    }

    .ac-one p, .ac-two p, .ac-three p, .ac-four p {
        padding-left: 160px;
    }

.ac-container input:checked ~ .ac-two {
    height: 280px;
    background: url('../images/logo_360view.jpg') no-repeat;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.ac-container input:checked ~ .ac-three {
    height: 940px;
    background: url('../images/logo_marketing.jpg') no-repeat;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.ac-container input:checked ~ .ac-four {
    height: 400px;
    background: url('../images/logo_payment.jpg') no-repeat;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.ac-five {
    background: url('../images/logo_content.jpg') no-repeat;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.ac-six {
    background: url('../images/logo_partners.jpg') no-repeat;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Relevant HTML

```
<article id="platform" class="ac-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row titleset">
        <div class="sixteen columns">
        <h2 class="remove-bottom">The Platform</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="row ">
        <input id="ac-1" name="accordian-1" type="radio" checked />
        <label for="ac-1">
            <h3 class="sectionblock">Who Needs LGC?</h3>
        </label>
        <div class="ac-one">
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
                <p class="centeredp"><h4>Start-ups,</h4></p>
                <p class="centeredp">looking for a complete turnkey solution.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
                <p class="centeredp"><h4>Corporate Start-Ups,</h4></p>
                <p class="centeredp">You're already an established player, but you need to launch a new brand or enter a new territory quickly.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
                <p class="centeredp"><h4>Existing Operators,</h4></p>
                <p class="centeredp">You might be an established player that needs to move to a powerful and cost-effective platform.  Or you may need an efficient way to integrate content from all our content partners.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- ac-one -->
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <input id="ac-2" name="accordian-1" type="radio" />
        <label for="ac-2">
            <h3 class="sectionblock">Player Management</h3>
        </label>
        <div class="ac-two">
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
                <p>360 degree view of the customer.</p>
                <p class="alert">Support for x currencies and x languages.</p>
                <p>Support for popular CMS system, Wordpress.</p>
                <p>Out of the box solutions for all typical pages such as registration, deposits, account management.</p>
                <p>Bespoke services available to customise these pages to suit your needs.</p>
                <p class="alert">[insert reporting].</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- ac-two -->
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <input id="ac-3" name="accordian-1" type="radio" />
        <label for="ac-3">
            <h3 class="sectionblock">Marketing</h3>
        </label>
        <div class="ac-three">
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
                <p><h4>Market-leading bonus functionality:</h4></p>
                <p>Deposit/sign-up</p>
                <p>Free spins</p>
                <p>Cash</p>
                <p class="alert">Insert something about segmentation, ease-of-use</p>
            </div>
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
                <p><h4>Loyalty system:</h4></p>
                <p>Multi-tier loyalty system proven to increase customer retention and spend</p>
                <p>Players progress through Bronze, Silver and Gold tiers accumulating points through their turnover or rake</p>
                <p>Players increase the rate at which points accumulate as they progress through the tiers</p>
            </div>
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
                <p><h4>CRM:</h4></p>
                <p class="alert">Insert text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
                <p><h4>Affiliate System:</h4></p>
                <p class="alert">Insert text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
                <p><h4>LGC's Best of Both World's Approach</h4></p>
                <p>We've partnered with the industry's premier content providers to give you a complete product portfolio at the flick of a switch.</p>
                <p>We run an open platform that also gives you room for bespoke content to suit your own market's needs.</p>
                <p>300 + desktop games available now.</p>
                <p>25 mobile games available now.</p>
                <p><a href="#content">Click here to see more</a></p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- ac-three -->
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <input id="ac-4" name="accordian-1" type="radio" />
        <label for="ac-4">
            <h3 class="sectionblock" for="ac-4">Payment Systems</h3>
        </label>
        <div class="ac-four">
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
            <p><h4>Out of the box support for:</h4></p>
            <p class="image_gallery_pay">
                <img src="./images/logo_visa.png" />
                <img src="./images/logo_mastercard.png" />
                <img src="./images/logo_neteller.png" />
                <img src="./images/logo_paysafe.png" />
                <img src="./images/logo_ukash.png" />
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="one-full-column headset">
            <p><h4>Our payment managements system gives you:</h4></p>
            <p>Real time reporting and fraud-management tools</p>
            <p>Transaction routing to guarantee the lowest transaction fees</p>
            <p>Make use of aggregated commercial arrangements to guarantee the lowest prices</p>
            <p>Quick access to over 100 different payment methods</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- ac-four -->
    </div>
    </div><!-- accordion -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
</article>

<article id="content" class="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row titleset">
            <div class="sixteen columns">
            <h2 class="remove-bottom">Content</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="ac-five">
                <div class="two-third-column headset">
                    <p>We've partnered with the industry's premier content providers to give you a complete product portfolio at the flick of a switch.</p>
                    <p>Excellent content is at the heart of our approach.  The best-of-breed content from our partners below, coupled with LGC’s powerful marketing tools, ensures operators see maximum return on investment.</p>
                    <p>Additionally, we run an open platform that gives you room to integrate bespoke content to suit your own market's needs.</p>
                    <p>300 + desktop games available now</p>
                    <p>25 mobile games available now</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row ">
    <div class="one-full-column headset">
        <p><h4>Our Casino Partners</h4></p>
        <p class="image_gallery">
            <a href="http://www.leandergames.com" target="_blank"><img src="./images/logo_leander.png" height="80" width="120" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.amayagaming.com" target="_blank"><img src="./images/logo_amaya.png" height="80" width="120" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.rivalpowered.com" target="_blank"><img src="./images/logo_rival.png" height="80" width="120" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.airdice.com" target="_blank"><img src="./images/logo_airdice.png" height="80" width="120" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.ezugi.com" target="_blank"><img src="./images/logo_ezugi.png" height="80" width="120" /></a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-full-column headset">
        <p><h4>Sportsbook</h4></p>
        <p>We have partnered with two leading sportsbook providers:
        <p class="image_gallery">
            <img src="./images/logo_betconstruct.png" height="80" width="120" />
            <img src="./images/logo_betinaction.png" height="80" width="120" />
        </p>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="two-third-column headset">
        <p>You can choose to run a fully-managed book that uses the risk parameters you set, allowing you to offer a sportsbook without the need for expensive traders.</p>
        <p>Desktop and mobile versions available.</p>
        <p>Access to virtual sports products.</p>
    </div>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</article>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update the question with relevant code to reproduce the issue...

Comment: And/or create a fiddle/codepen example which we could edit

Comment: I'm not so sure you could do that with pure CSS, you would have to either compensate for the height added with scrollTop, or wrap the whole accordion and use negative top margins to compensate for the height added.. that's what I have.

Comment: All the headers are within a very close region to one another, is there a way to have the css absolute position the view to the first linked header?

Comment: Anchor tags _might_ work for that. I'm not sure if the nesting in/around the input like you're doing will work though.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle if anyone wants to mess around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/WKnQN/

Comment: I tried an anchor tag, but it seems to deactivate the css accordion.

Comment: If I try the anchor tag, it deactivates the css accordion, any advice on getting an anchor to still work with the css accordion?